# Running Power to detcached studio

Tags: electrical-panel

I will be running power to detached studio that is about 50ft from my home. The studio will have 6 canned lights, 1 chandelier, 2 porch lights, and 6 receptacles. The studio will also have a 115v mini split AC that pulls 10.4 amps. My plan is to have a sub panel with two 20 amp breakers. One breaker would feed the circuit for lights and outlets and one would feed power to AC with disconnect outside. Can I use a 30 amp breaker to feed from my main panel with 10/3 wire or do I need a 40 amp breaker with 8/3?

Comment: It depends an *awful* lot on *what else* you plan to plug into those receptacles.  With 10/3 you don't have much breathing room for expansion, so for instance if you want to add a PC and laser printer, or table saw and dust collector, you'll be in  trouble!   Also, subpanels are dirt cheap and please consider one with lots of space, e.g. I would fit nothing less than a 20-space panel, and you'll want one with a "main breaker" so it provides the requisite shut-off switch.

Comment: Really depends what type of studio yours is, and what you want to plug into the 6 recepts. For example, my friend calls his photography studio a studio, but he also has quite a bit of computer load and a lot of speciaty high powered (not LED) lighting for photo shoots.

Comment: @Tyson I can't blame him for not using LED.  You need excellent CRI for photography, and LED isn't there at any affordable price.  Fluorescent is just getting there.  Old days the advice was go HMI, but that's not true color either.

Comment: We probably need a little more information. First when you talk about 10/3 or 8/3 to an electrician. It usually means you are using a 10/3 cable with a ground and the ground is never counted as a conductor. So are referring to 10/2 cable and running just a 120V or a 10/3 and running 240V? Second are you sure you are installing a 10.4A 115V split AC? I am not saying you don't have one I have just never seen one. Most 115V AC's are window units and are fractional ton units.

Comment: @Harper Just pointing out that it all depends what is intended use for the outlets.  If I took on OPs project I'd start at 50 or 60 amps 240v, then consider what future use might be and consider raising from there.  Space heaters anyone?

Comment: @Tyson that's a good point, it might matter what else OP plans to plug into those receptacles.  You're right, I don't think s/he has much breathing room with 10/3, cable isn't cheap but trenching is worse.

Comment: @Harper  Yup, $50 or $100 more in materials now is nothing compared to starting from scratch again when it gets cold because he forgot the plasma tv is 10 amps, the computer etc is 4, and the two space heaters are another 20 combined, and there's a potters wheel with a 3/4 hp motor 

Comment: Is there a reason not to bury a conduit to the shed so that you don't have to dig things up again?

Comment: Another thing to consider: do you use your studio at night? If you accidentally plug too much in to the receptacles or worse something shorts out and trips the breaker, you'll be left in the dark (so consider a separate breaker for lights in the subpanel). And if you trip the breaker back in the house, you'll have to get back to the house without the benefit of the exterior lighting, too (but if you use a bigger one there, then the closer subpanel breaker will hopefully trip instead).